Object of type 'TypeError' is not JSON serializable added code receives same error message
I am using django and pymongo to code a flashcard app I am using csv files on mongodb compass. I have seen this error posted before however, when I tried to fix it I get the same error from the server here is my code below. when i google this error code to fix it also does not fix the error.
views.py
import json
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Card, myapp_collection
from django.http import HttpResponse




class CardListView(ListView):
    model = Card
    queryset = Card.objects.all().order_by('box', '-date_created')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Prepare flashcards data from MongoDB for template
        flashcards_data = [...]  # Replace [...] with the processed flashcards data
        flashcards_json = json.dumps(flashcards_data)

        context['flashcards_json'] = flashcards_json
        return context
    
    

models.py



# cards/models.py

from django.db import models
from .db_con import db

myapp_collection = db["myapp"]

NUM_BOXES = 5
BOXES = range(1, NUM_BOXES + 1)

class Card(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    box = models.IntegerField(
        choices=zip(BOXES, BOXES),
        default=BOXES[0],
    )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    
def __str__(self):
        return self.question

card_list.html


<!-- cards/templates/myapp/base.html -->
{% extends "cards/base.html" %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Flashcards</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Flashcards App</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
            <h2>Welcome to your Flashcards app!</h2>
        {% endblock content %}
    </main>
</body>

</html>

